# JavaScript: clock and the Date()

Tags: javascript

So I have this clock script:

```
function digitalWatch(timestamp) {
    var date = new Date(timestamp);
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    document.getElementById("digital_watch").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    setTimeout(function(){digitalWatch(timestamp+1)}, 1000);
}
digitalWatch(<<here I pass a UNIX timestamp from server>>)
```

The clock don't work.
I debuged it with console.log() and I saw that timestamp incremented correctly but the Date() constructor returns the same result again and again.

Someone knows what's the problem here? And how can I solve it?

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNIX timestamps count in seconds, JavaScript timestamps count in milliseconds.

You should just multiply the passed timestamp by 1000, e.g.:

```
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
```

This will not only fix the initial conversion, but ensure that when you add a second (in the timer callback) that you actually do add 1 second, and not just 1 millisecond.  The latter is the reason that you *appear* to be getting the same `Date` object back - you're almost certainly not, but the new one is only 1ms later than the previous so will show the same `HH:MM:SS` value *most* of the time.

In practise, note that you'll find that `setTimeout` does not guarantee that the events will fire 1000ms apart so you will get some clock drift.

You ought to take into account how long the preceding code takes to run too - indeed a better approach may be to simply determine the difference between the originally supplied timestamp and the local computer's time, and use that as a reference value for all subsequent calls.

Comment: @c00p3r.web Remember to update your increment to add 1000ms instead of 1ms.

Comment: changed my code a bit. Now I multiply in the func instead of outside of it

Comment: @c00p3r.web that should work better - in your old version you were also doing `timestamp + 1` which would only add 1ms at a time instead of 1 second, but multiplying inside the function (per my answer) fixes that issue too.